# iPhone SDK custom view loaded from XIB is not displaying?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, xib

I have created a custom view hierarchy in an XIB that I want to place on various other view controller's view.  The hints from SO indicate that I have to explicitly add as a subview.  The XIB loads and viewing it in the debugger, it looks correct, however, there are two problems.  First, it only defines the toplevel UIView of my custom XIB and that does not display.  I have purposely put a different color background to make it obvious.  The code for the parent "OtherViewController" that is trying to load this custom view as its header is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__  );
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        appDelegate = (myProjectAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSObject *obj = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PageHeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
        NSArray *array = nil;

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

            array = (NSArray*) obj;

            for (UIView *customView in array) {
                NSLog(@"%@", customView);
                if ((customView.tag == 3700) && ([customView isKindOfClass:[PageHeaderView class]])) {
                    [self setCustomPageHeaderView: (PageHeaderView*) customView];
                    [self.view addSubview: customPageHeaderView];
                    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: customView];
                }

                NSArray *array = [self.customPageHeaderView subviews];
                for (NSObject *obj in array) {
                    NSLog(@"%s: \t%@", __FUNCTION__, obj);
                }
            }
        } else { 
            NSLog(@"%s: object following loadNibNamed is [%@]", __FUNCTION__, [obj class]);
        }

    }

    return self;
}
```

The TAG = 3700 was again to have an obvious bit of information in the debugger.  It shows up in the custom view as expected.

Comment: BTW - the hierarchy of subviews are showing up in the debugger (I must have been blind or I accidentally fixed something by the time I posted this code and question).  I cannot determine if they are children or orphans.

Comment: Hey all - I got it so work ... I added an else clause for all of the other views in the array to be subviews and it works.  I cannot answer the question for 24 hours, so if someone else wants to be the hero, I will award the answer.  ....               } else {
                    [self.view addSubview: customView];
                    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: customView];
                }

Comment: wrong again - there was only one custom view with its hierarchy and the loop on "subviews" were then used to hook-up the delegate text-field view properties of my VC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access the `self.view` property for the first time, the view controller lazy-loads its view by calling `loadView`, which loads the view from a NIB by default.  By accessing `self.view` within your `initWithNibName:bundle:` method, you're asking the view controller to load its view before the controller has even finished initializing.

Try moving this code to `viewDidLoad:`.  That will guarantee that `self.view` has already been lazy-loaded by the time you access it.

Comment: That makes sense.  My code is now working inside initWithNibName:bundle: , but that may be a race condition waiting to happen.  I will move the code and see if I get the same results.

Comment: I moved the code to viewDidLoad: since it was already working, I don't see any difference, but hopefully I have a more stable life cycle for the app. +1